# The volume you have selected may not be mirrored

Tags: windows-7, raid, ntfs, windows-server-2012

We have been running a mirrored 2-drive setup happily since installing windows 7.  However now that a sale has allowed us to add a third disk we are unable to locate an instruction manual or obvious Disk Management action to either add a new drive to an existing mirror, extend an existing mirror to a new device, or break/re-create the mirror across more than two devices (the dialogue does not seem to allow multiple disk selection).

This is additionally frustrating since every other modern operating system, even free ones, has supported multiply redundant RAID-1 storage for a very long time.  Windows 7 Ultimate surely also supports that solution?

---

I created the first mirror using DISKPART by following the steps above.  Now, I'm trying to add the another hard drive (disk 3) with the same model and size to it.

---

**Note**: This question is a quote of the un-answered question on [Microsoft Support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-7ultimate-raid-1-mirror-across-3-or-more/f97719f2-c6f3-4202-8cf8-df35e01df864?messageId=406b3ada-79a2-463e-a9e3-50e28baf5c20). The support engineer didn't even bother to search the Windows source code for the error, and the thread is locked so everyone is prevented for helping each other. Fortunately SuperUser supports helping people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that NTFS only allows you to have two disks participate in a RAID-1 mirror.

- if you attempt to use **Disk Management** to add a 3rd disk, the option cannot be found
- if you attempt to use `diskpart` to manually add a disk to the volume, you get the error:

  ```
  The volume you have selected may not be mirrored.
  Please select a different volume to mirror.
  ```

---

The full command that you would run would be:

```
DISKPART> select volume 0

Volume 0 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> add

The volume you have selected may not be mirrored.
Please select a different volume to mirror.
```